# PHP variables built out of string and vars

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have a need to build a dynamic query that requires a variable to structured like so;

```
$my_var = $var_1.'_'.$var_2.'_band_'.$var_3;
```

$my_var is then used within a loop.

While I can echo the $my_var data successfully, this does not work in my loop. Is this even a possibility?

Here is the actual loop. $my_var would be used as a lookup for a column title. The vars used in $my_var would be strings.

```
global $wpdb;

    $my_var = $var_1.'_'.$var_2.'_band_'.$var_3;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM quote WHERE Postcode_area LIKE '%$find%'" );

    foreach ( $results as $result ) {
        $savings = $result->$my_var * 52;
    }
```

**SOLVED**

Thank you everyone for your input, I'm sorry to say I was being a complete idiot! The column I was using to lookup data as a test did not required one additional VAR. Truly sorry to waste anyones time!

The loop is now working without issue.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Which variables do you have? And what you have tried so far?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what is your current output? what is your expected output?

Comment: I have updated the question. The expected output would be a INT result from a column lookup which is then used as a sum.

Comment: Try using braces: `$result->{$my_var}`

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, try using braces:

```
$result->{$my_var}
```

This practice is demonstrated in the manual a quarter of the way down under the **"Complex (curly) syntax"**: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php